# How can I audit commands executed by each user in the Terminal?

Tags: command-line

I have two users on my Ubuntu desktop. I want to **audit** the commands that these two users execute each day. I am not talking about the History command, because I need to know the commands each user executed specifically.

I cannot log in as or `su` to either of these users.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: You could tee the log to syslog and then have a remote daemon forward all the syslog to another machine that you can use. I guess you will have su to the user atleast once and setup the bash_profile/bashrc to forward the history to syslog.

Answer (score 1):

Install acct :

```
sudo apt-get install acct
```

For example: as a client user I execute the `rm` command:

```
client@client:~$ rm /mnt/test
```

Now from my root account (or any account) I can know when this user executed the `rm` command:

```
root@client:~# lastcomm client | grep rm
rm                     client   pts/0            0.00 secs  Tue Mar   4 01:53
```

As we see here the it displays the time.

What if I want to know all the commands that client executed?

You can type `lastcomm client`

If you have many users just change the `client` to the users you have: it will display commands executed by each, along with the time.